# Split function doesnt work for string and for list

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, split, numbered-list

Just doing one of my first web scraping and I already have elements I wanted to extract but I cannot find the function to print them as a numbered list. The code I have for now:

```
r = requests.get('https://mmazurek.dev/category/programowanie-2/page/3/', proxies={'http':'82.119.170.106'})

page = soup(r.content, "html.parser")

contents=page.findAll(None, class_="post-title-link")

for content in contents:
    text_content=list(content.get_text())
    first_letter=str(text_content[0])
    x="".join(first_letter)  

    listToStr = "".join(map(str, text_content))

    print(listToStr)
```

The purpose is to have list printed like:

1. P....
2. J...
3. ...

Hope you dont mind it's a Polish text;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def get_html(url, useragent=None, proxy=None):
    session = requests.Session()
    request = session.get(url=url, headers=useragent, proxies=proxy)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs(request.text, 'lxml')
        return soup
    else:
        print("Error " + str(request.status_code))
        return request.status_code


def parse(soup):
    data = []
    contents = soup.findAll(None, class_="post-title-link")
    for i, content in enumerate(contents):
        text = content.text
        href = content['href']
        data.append([
            i,
            text,
            href,
        ])

    return data

    return data

data = parse(get_html('https://mmazurek.dev/category/programowanie-2/page/3/', proxy={'http': '82.119.170.106'}))

print(data)
```